# Need help creating an XML grammar verifier (C++)

Tags: c++, xml, grammar

I must create a program which takes in a file and prints the interpretation if the file is formatted correctly, and handle the errors otherwise. I think I can write the program once I have some idea where to start conceptually, but as of now I am in way over my head.

It must accept three tags,

- A tab, "< tab >(no spaces)" indents the content by a single tab
- Paragraph, "< p >" prints content followed by new line
- List item, "< listItem >" prints text preceded by a bullet "*"

and < /tab > closes the content that will be tabbed, etc.

Content can also be inside multiple tags.

I am also encouraged to implement this recursively, and I don't quite understand how recursion would help in this case. 
If anyone could point me in a direction on how to get started, it would be greatly appreciated. I have so far tried using an input stream to read in a word, check if it is one of the tags, and then putting the following content into a queue, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, this site is best for factual questions and not help on how to start projects. Regardless, I would advise you to consider using a real XML parser versus writing a hand-made one. Try checking out Expat. Good luck!

Comment: This obviously sounds like an assignment of sorts, so an external library probably isn't of much use to OP.

I would start with figuring out what constitutes a "properly formatted" file. Once you've defined that, moving forward is usually fairly straightforward.